# ActionMethod to return excel application content

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

What's the correct method to return application/ms-excel content type from an action method in MVC?

I've tried creating a controller action method and passing the controller context, such as;

```
public void ExportToExcel(MyViewModel model, ControllerContext context)
{
    .... build up html or xml excel output in Writer

    context.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
    context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "applicaton/vnd.ms-excel";
    context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader(.. etc.);
    context.HttpContext.Response.Write(Writer.ToString());
    context.HttpContext.Response.End();
}
```

When trying to use the controller context as above I get a method or operation not implemented exception when calling any method of the Response object.

I've also tried returning a FileResult, FileContentResult and ContentResult action result types which seem to just throw my content to the browser.

EDIT: Here's my code for the ExcelResult class;

```
public class ExcelResult : ActionResult
{
    private string _content = String.Empty;
    public string Content
    {
        get {

            return _content;
        }

        set {

            _content = value;
        }
    }



    public ExcelResult(string content)
    {
        this.Content = content;
    }



    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        context.HttpContext.Response.Charset = "iso-8859-1";
        context.HttpContext.Response.BufferOutput = true;
        context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename = exportdata.xls");
        context.HttpContext.Response.Write(this.Content);
        context.HttpContext.Response.End();
    }


}
```

Comment: To add to this I have also now implmented a custom ActionResult class called ExcelResult that implements the above code in the ExecuteResult method. This gives the same result, i.e. it justs writes to output to the browser. I've used Fiddler to view the response header data, but it all looks ok?

Comment: Show us your `ExcelResult` code. I have done something similar and it is working for me.

Comment: As stated, using the above code in the overridden ExecuteResult() method.

Comment: Ok, then post the whole relevant code please - the controller action where you are returning the `ExcelResult`.

Comment: OK, here's ExcelResult class.

Comment: Try changing this line `context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "exportdata.xls");` to this `context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=exportdata.xls");`

Comment: Sorry for delay. No sorry. That was part of my original code and I did update the op code snippet to reflect. It seems that using the 'File' controller extension method and returning a `FileResult` from the action method should also produce the download of an excel file or whatever file you specify by adding the `'content-disposition' 'attachment; filename='` header. I've tried all of these methods, and I've used fiddler to inspect the response headers. All looks fine but every time the content is just sent to the browser as if it were an action result.

Comment: Now I tried your code and it works for me (it forces the file to be downloaded instead of displayed directly in a browser). Could you post the code where you are using this class to return an action result?

Comment: @twoflower let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2717/discussion-between-jez-and-twoflower)

Answer (score 0):

FYI. My problem was due to the fact I was trying to change content-type from an AJAX callback. Always ensure you are submitting a form before changing the content-type.